# NHibernate - code example for update

Tags: nhibernate

I've been trying all day to get one of my object to be saved with versions but to no avail. Please point out  what I'm doing wrong, as I've tried `SaveOrUpdate`, `Merge()` and `Update()` after a `Clear()` call.

**The business object:**

```
 public class MappedTest  
{  
    public virtual Guid TestID { get; set; }  
    public virtual int VersionID { get; set; }  
    public virtual byte[] Content { get; set;}  
    public virtual DateTime DateSaved { get; set; }  
}
```

**The mapping:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>  
<hibernate-mapping ...>  
 <class name="TestImp.Definition.MappedTest, PythonTest" table="Tests">  
  <id name="TestID" unsaved-value="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000">  
  <generator class="guid"/>  
</id>  
<version name="VersionID" column="VersionID" />  
<property name="Content" column="TestObject" type="BinaryBlob"/>  
<property name="DateSaved" column="Date"/>
```

`

**The actual code:**

```
using (var session = new Configuration().Configure().BuildSessionFactory().OpenSession())  
        {  
            using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())  
            {  
                if(session.Get<MappedTest>(mappedTest.TestID) == null)  
                {  
                    session.Save(mappedTest);  
                }  
                else  
                {  
                session.Clear();  
                    session.Update(mappedTest);  
                }  
                transaction.Commit();  
            }  
        }`
```

Thanks.

Comment: What value for VersionID does it save the entity with in the event it isn't in the database?  Are you actually updating the mappedTest object in the else statement?  If nothing is changing in the object it may not be issuing an update statement to the database.  Have you checked the logs or sql output for the queries that are actually being ran against the db?

Comment: It's saved with VersionID = 1. The code above is called from a test, where first I create the test and call it, and then update it and call it. I'm not sure about versions in NHibernate - I'd expect to see 2 lines, one with VersionID =1 (and old mappedTest) and one with VersionID=2 (and new object). Is this correct? About viewing SQL - I'm trying to now. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For insert try just with:

```
using (var session = new Configuration().Configure().BuildSessionFactory().OpenSession())  
    {  
        MappedTest mappedTest =new MappedTest();

        using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())  
        {  
            session.SaveOrUpdate(mappedTest);  
            transaction.Commit();  
        }  
    }
```

for update:

```
using (var session = new Configuration().Configure().BuildSessionFactory().OpenSession())  
    {  
        MappedTest mappedTest =session.Get<MappedTest>(..an Id..);
        mappedTest.YourProperty="newValue";

        using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())  
        {  
            session.SaveOrUpdate(mappedTest);  
            transaction.Commit();  
        }  
    }
```

If you need it try use a `session.Flush()` to force database operations.

Comment: Will it work if my mappedTest is a kind of wrapper around a bigger object, and the bigger object is the one being edited? The mapped one is created by serializing a part of the bigger object (because we used our own DAL before and now checking to see if NHibernate can be a better idea).

Comment: Sorry I cannot follow you! "a kind of wrapper"... what do you mean? Is it related to your example?

Comment: Let me rephrase: I have a complicated object, Test, that we serialized when we wrote our own DAL layer. This results in a MappedTest object. What I do in my code is, create a Test, create a MappedTest out of it, and then using NHibernate to save it to the DB. Later, I change the original Test, which means I have another MappedTest object, with the same ID, that I want to update in the DB. If it's not clear yet (sorry), I'll edit the code.

Comment: If you have a mapped nhibernate object with a property contains another object you need to map both! I think it is a good idea to show your actual complex mapping because I think the simple example you  posted works without problems.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility that took me some time to realize and is not covered yet on this thread: In such case, check if your mapper is set on ReadOnly. NHibernate does not tell anything when asked to save or update with a ReadOnly mapper.